# Combining Netflix Zuul with Netflix Hystrix

Tags: java, groovy, netflix, hystrix, netflix-zuul

I'm a big fan of the Open Source project of Netflix. They made some really cool stuff.

I have set up a Zuul and that is working fine. Created all kind of filters and those are dynamically loaded and run.

What I now try to do is use Hystrix inside a filter. What I see is that if everything when fine it all works. But when there is a exception inside the run() method Zuul is catching it instead of Hystrix. So the getFallback() is never called.

I shared my code [Github](https://gist.github.com/peerke/5e44365cb947fcdf84cd#file-httprequest-groovy).

Somebody has any idea how Hystrix can catch the exception instead of Zuul?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is actually with how you are executing your hystrix command. Try calling [execute()](https://netflix.github.io/Hystrix/javadoc/com/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCommand.html#execute()) instead of [run()](https://netflix.github.io/Hystrix/javadoc/com/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCommand.html#run()). I suspect that what's happening is run() is simply throwing the exception whereas execute() will catch it and call getFallback().